# C# winform set value and name of combobox item from DataTable

Tags: c#, mysql, .net, winforms, combobox

I want to list fims inside winforms combobox. So am trying to set combobox to have `id` like value and firm `name` like item name. Am getting list of firms from `mysql` database.

`SELECT id, name FROM  firms`

**So my code is here:**

```
private void FirmSelect_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Firm firm = new Firm(); //db model
    DataTable data = firm.ListAlllFirm();
    FirmComboBox.DataSource = data;
    FirmComboBox.DisplayMember = "name";
}
```

This work good but i want to set firm id as item value! Does i need to interate `DataTable` with `foreach` and manually set it?  How can i do that?

Or any other way to do this;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't want to Loop Through the collection to Set the ItemValue,

> You can use the [`ValueMember`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listcontrol.valuemember(v=vs.110).aspx) property of the `ComboBox` for this,
>   Which will allows you to Gets or sets the path of the property to use
>   as the actual value for the items in the ListControl.

This can be done by using the following code:

```
FirmComboBox.DisplayMember = "name";
FirmComboBox.ValueMember = "id";
FirmComboBox.DataSource = Data;
```

So that you can access the Value Field by using `FirmComboBox.SelectedValue`

Comment: I already try it! But when i try to test first item start with zero `0`. In database i has auto increment `id` and there has no firm with `0` id

Comment: @Ivan : Cool Happy to Help you. Don't forget to Mark it as accepted if it really helps you